# Алгоритм Гровера и его применение для поиска индекса элемента в массиве

Tags: база-данных, поиск

я новичок в квантовых вычисления и не могу разобраться с одним вопросом, связанным с алгоритмом Гровера. Есть задача: дан массив данных [2,6,7,8,0,5,3,1] и необходимо определить индекс, под которым в этом массиве расположено число 7. Как решить данную задачу с помощью алгоритма Гровера?

Answer (score 1):

Если прочитать [описание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), то становится понятно, что для решения такой задачи вам понадобится, кроме совтеов на этом форуме, квантовый компьютер, состоящий из "о-большое от логарифма длинны последовательности" кубитов.

Можно "поиграться в песочнице", предоставляемой, например, [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/). Правда, на том уровне, на котором это программируется сейчас, я так понимаю, всё будет сводиться к строке кода "найти индекс с помощью алгоритма Гровера", то есть, Вам будет предложено воспользоваться стандартной библиотекой :-)

В целом же, квантовые компьютеры - это штуки, котрые требуют нехилой математической подготовки, и имеют довольно маленькое отношение к програмированию в том виде, в котором мы его знаем сейчас. Даже так: знания программирования на классичских компьютерах направляют мышление в сторону, которая не соответствует принципам работы квантовых компьютеров.

Если бы кто то поделился более полным ответом на вопрос - я был бы рад.